# what causes a car to spit and sputter while driving then shuts off when stopped and smells like rotten eggs and make a squaling kind of noise?

Tags: engine

I have 2016 Chevrolet Cruze LT 4 cyl, and since the weather started turning warmer I've been using the AC sometimes. Since using the AC I have noticed several times, just randomly it would act like it was hesitating and then it started spitting and sputtering. Then I'd smell a foul smell like rotten eggs. Then along with the smell, I get the spit & sputtering and a squealing sound. Now when I start it up it likes rumbles and shakes after a few minutes, the first start up seems fine, but a few minutes not even 3 minutes later it starts rumbling and sputtering again. I'm afraid to drive it to have it tested for any codes, afraid I'll break down along side the highway. Any suggestions, I've been told that it's my whole engine. I really hope not, because I just purchased this vehicle from a dealership in October.

Comment: Get an OBD scanner, plug it in the OBD port and post the PTC codes, if you can. Anyway, the rotten eggs smell, along with the sputtering, is definitely too much gasoline getting inside the converter (misfire).

Comment: The rotten egg smell is hydrogen sulfide. It may be due to sulfur in the fuel or it may be coming from the battery.

Comment: Oh, and the squealing sound is probably your belt slipping. Check the belt tension and the condition of the accessories driven by that belt.

Comment: The squealing could be the AC belt - turn off the AC and defroster and see if it goes away.  As far as sputtering/smell... some cars have a hard time when the weather gets significantly warmer (or colder) "overnight" - some of the engine operational settings are "remembered" ( in memory). The settings will *eventually* adjust.  It  might take a few restarts.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try these avenues. I'll let you know if this has helped any.

Comment: Is the AC cold anyway?

Comment: A/C's are notorious for all kinds of disgusting odors, especially when they're not used all that much in humid conditions. Various descriptions of the smell are given by people ranging from 'wet dog' to fungi to rotten eggs. Best way to get rid of it is an ozone treatment or just using the A/C a lot.

Comment: @Bart The problem is, until he posts the results of an OBD scan (don't need to drive the car anywhere, many OBD scanners that show codes are available for cheap), we can't be sure if he's having a seizing AC compressor or a misfiring engine or anything else.